# Inferences from Euler formula, a sufficient condition?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

The conclusions from the Euler formula are:

- $|E| <= 3 * |V| - 6$ and
- $deg(v) <= 5$

If a graph satisfies these conditions, is that a sufficient condition for a graph to be drawn planar? Or is it necessary to check additional things (like $K_{5}$ or $K_{3,3}$)?

Comment: $\text{deg}(v)\le 5$ may need refinement if different vertices have different degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $K_5$ and subdivide all its edges (replace edge $uv$ by two edges $uw,wv$). This graph has $15$ vertices and $20$ edges and average degree less than $5$, but it is clearly non-planar because $K_5$ is a minor of it.

[image]

Comment: Could you make a graphical example of this? (Because at $K_5$ a contradiction to the conclusion is found $3*|V|-6 <= |E|$ -> $9 <= 10$ (the 9 should be greater than 10))

Comment: @JAdel You can do it yourself. Just draw $K_5$ and then add little circles in the middle of the edges.

Comment: @JAdel Fine, I added an image.